# How to "stick" two numbers together in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a simple discount calculator. These are my variables:

```
percentage = float(raw_input('Percentage: '))
price = float(raw_input('Price: $'))
discount = price*percentage
finalPrice = price - discount
```

At the moment, I have to enter "0.50" to calculate a 50% discount, but, I'd like to simply enter "50". Is there a simple way to add "0." to whichever number is entered as a percentage, as in, `'0.' + 'percentage'`, so that it results in `'0.percentage'`?

Comment: Stick a 0. in front of a number, get 0.9 where user meant 9%. Fail.

Comment: Obligatory: Please don't use `float` for money. Use `decimal.Decimal` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why don't you simply divide the number by 100?

Comment: `percentage = float(raw_input('Percentage: '))/100`

Comment: Of course! This works and is a lot less cumbersome. I've never been proficient at math, as you can tell. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple:

```
float(50)/float(100)
```